# A Productivity App Built in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to build the sample code in Swift provided by Apple

[A Productivity App Built in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister-Swift/Introduction/Intro.html)

But when I ran it, it pop up an error like this:

> "Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1"

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: what are you running it on? device or simulator?

Comment: And are you on OS X 10.9 or 10.10? I don't think that project is compatible with OS X 10.9.

Comment: I used simulator on OS X 10.10

Comment: I have the same issue and I am a registered developer with the appropriate profile imported. I don't think the issue is not being a registered developer.

Comment: I am registered for iOS only. I got rid of the OSX directories hoping that would let me in, but it didn't. I was getting an error that the Apple ID was not registered for iCloud. I fixed that, and still get the error.

Answer (score 10):

The actual cause is because xcode cannot code sign:

```
iPhone Developer: no identity found
**error: Couldn't codesign /Users/zhaoj5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lister-hehrkmcyuflnfucnsqcofjotmglo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.ListerToday.appex/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1**
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1
```

This is because you are not a registered Apple Developer. If you go to project -> General, you will see there is a warning:

"This product type must be built using a provisioning profile, however, no signing identity or provisioning profile was specified, Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the member center."

There is a button "Fix Issue", you can enter your account information once you become a registered developer.

Answer (score 2):

As the flip side to not being set up with a developer profile, I ran into this problem as a result of having duplicate certificates set up. Once I deleted all but one, Lister finally compiled.

Answer (score 0):

As volatilevar mentioned, it's a problem with the project settings, though I assume you are a registered developer with access to the sample code and Yosemite beta. I had the same issue. The Provisioning Profile isn't selected because you downloaded the code and the previously selected profile doesn't exist!

1. If you installed Yosemite fresh, make sure you export your profile from Xcode where you were using it before and import it again in Yosemite.
2. Check that your profile and identity are correctly selected under General and Build Settings for the target.

If you need some guidance on moving your profile see [exporting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html) and [importing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set both Code Signing and Provisioning Profiles to "Automatic" under  My Project  -> Target My Project ->Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity  and Provisioning Profile